# Running 'install' command on dockerised App Service in Azure

Tags: azure, docker

I have a web API dockerized and published from Visual Studio. All I had to do was to choose the system (Linux it was) and hit publish.
Now the problem is I have to run command 
`RUN apt-get install -y libc6-dev` 
on my docker container but I can't find any access to it. Does any of you know how to install 'libc5-dev' on that kind of instance?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can either **include the installation command within your docker file** in order to get libc6-dev installed e. g.:

```
FROM YOURIMAGE
RUN apt-get install -y libc6-dev
```

Or you can **choose a different base image** that already has libc6-dev installed.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! The problem is I can not find any way to get a docker file or anything like that. Visual studio wants me to choose operating system and does the rest. When I go to "App services" page in the Azure portal there is no such thing as "used docker instance" or something like this :(

Comment: There should be a dockerfile inside your project root. See also: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/containerized-lifecycle-architecture/design-develop-containerized-apps/visual-studio-tools-for-docker

Comment: ok, thanks to your advice I have created dockerfile. When published api does not work at all. I am doing something wrong as certain.

Comment: Ok, instance works on Azure. Can I just add 'RUN apt-get install -y libc6-dev' at the bottom of my dockerfile?

Comment: You have to put it after the FROM line of the image you want to have the dependency installed

Comment: Looks like the container visual studio is using to deploy my API has nothing to do with dockerfile I created. I am afraid I will have to find another way to deploy it. Thank you anyway!